# Automate formula to selected rows for vise versa calculation

Tags: excel, vba

I want to filldown the formula below to row 4 to row 40:

```
If Target.Address = Range("E13").Address Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("H13").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("E13").Value * ActiveSheet.Range("G13")
    ElseIf Target.Address = Range("H13").Address Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("E13").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("H13").Value / ActiveSheet.Range("G13")
    End If
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume from your use of Target that the code is from a Worksheet_Change event procedure.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    if not intersect(target, Range("E4:E40, H4:H40")) is nothing then
        on error goto safe_exit
        application.enableevents = false
        dim t as range 
        for each t in intersect(target, Range("E4:E40, H4:H40"))
            select case t.column
                case 5
                    cells(t.row, "H") = cells(t.row, "E") * cells(t.row, "G")
                case 8
                    'you might want to make sure cells(t.row, "G") isn't zero
                    cells(t.row, "E") = cells(t.row, "H") / cells(t.row, "G")
            end select
        next t
    End If

safe_exit:
    application.enableevents = true
End Sub
```